# find set of complex numbers where $Arg(\frac{1}{z}) \neq -Arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

find set of complex numbers where $Arg(\frac{1}{z}) \neq -Arg(z)$

---

**Def**

$Arg(z)=\theta :z=re^{i \theta }  \wedge -\pi < \theta \leq \pi$

---

for z in first, second quadrant it holds except for when $\theta =\pi $ i think. also think most third quadrant hold. so far only found when $z=re^{i \pi}$. looked at the back of the book says zero also works but do not see it. since $Arg(0)=0 $ then $-Arg(0)=0$ and what is $Arg(1/0)=Arg( \infty)$? zero?

this is why  for $\pi $. let $z=re^{i\pi}$ then $Arg(z)=\pi \Rightarrow -Arg(z)=-\pi$. now
$$Arg(1/z)=Arg\left (\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\pi} \right)=\pi $$
so $-Arg(z)\neq Arg(1/z)$ when $z=re^{i \pi}$ ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=-1$ then Arg$(\frac{1}{z})$=Arg$(\frac{1}{-1})$=Arg$(-1)$=$\pi$. On the other hand Arg$(-1)$=$\pi$ so that  $$Arg(\frac{1}{-1})=\pi \ne -(Arg(-1))=-(\pi)$$